# k-fold cross validation of GAM in r

Tags: r, cross-validation, gam

Is there a way to do a k-fold cross validation of a GAM in R?

I have produced a GAM using the `mgcv` package.

I used the package `gamclass` to use `CVgam`, which gives me the output:

```
GAMscale CV-mse-GAM  
1.15e+09    7.26e+09
```

As far as I can tell, this isn't a useful output for 10-fold cross validation? Or is it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in function, but you could program your own.  I would start by trying to modify this code:  http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/hw/02/hw-02.R